# How to create a X.509V3 certificate without makecert or bouncy castle

Tags: x509certificate

Please Help. I must create a X.509V3 certificate without using makecert or Bouncy Castle library.  The purpose is to use theme in order to extract public key.

is it possible?

i can't do this... please can you help me

milles merci.

Comment: Please specify platform / language, as it's not clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that running a command line program will work for you, then you could try using the openssl tool.

First up, you'd want to generate a private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out new.key 4096
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus
...........................................................
.................................................................
...............................................................
............................................................++
........................++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

Then, generate a self signed certificate with it:

```
openssl req -new -key new.key -x509 -days 1095 -out new.crt
```

You'll be asked what values to put into the certificate before it's generated. You'll then have a private key and a x509 certificate with your values in.

Comment: think you very much, but is it possible to use open ssl for creating all types of public key. (RSA, ECRSA , Deffie-Hellman(DH) and ECDH)
i must design a tool that allows the customer to make the mechanism
 of encryption, decryption and signature.

Comment: Yup, the openssl command line tool is pretty flexible. See http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genpkey.html for the manual on how to control how your private key is generated (format, size etc)